# Is ARP source hardware address redundant?

Tags: protocols, mac-address, duplicate-data, arp

I'm working on a network security project and I noticed something that I can't explain:

Why do we need a source hardware address field in arp? Isn't it already contained in the ethernet header?

Comment: The only reason I've found that makes any sense is proxy ARP

Answer (score 3):

ARP is designed this way so that it can run over other hardware, not just Ethernet. Have a look [here](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/arp.htm).